# Using the Central Limit Theory to solve $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(n-\sqrt n \lt X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\lt n+\sqrt n)$

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables that are uniformly distributed between 0 and 2. What is:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(n-\sqrt n \lt X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\lt n+\sqrt n)$$

Attempt:

$\sigma^2=\frac{1}{3}$
$\mu=1$

So is the idea to get what we have into the form of the following so we can use z-score values?

$$\mathbb{P}\left(a\lt\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n -\mu_x}{\displaystyle\frac{\sigma_x}{\sqrt n}}\lt b\right)$$ and then n$\rightarrow \infty$ we get $\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)$. Is my thought process correct?

Edit: my attempt:

Set $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n =\bar X$

Subtract $n$ from both sides and we get:
$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\bar X -n\right|\lt \sqrt n\right)$

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\left|\bar X -n\right|}{\sqrt{n}}\lt 1\right)$$

And now I believe I am stuck.

Comment: The general idea  is right. The variance of $X_i$ is not quite right.

Comment: Shouldnt variance be $1/3$?

Comment: @Qwerty correct. should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ I believe

Comment: @RonaldB Standard deviation=${1\over \sqrt 3}$ Not variance

Comment: @RonaldB Please correct your variance It is $1/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\over n}-\mu\over \sigma/\sqrt{n}}\sim N(0,1)$$$$\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\sum X_i-n\over \sqrt{n\over 3}}\sim N(0,1)$$$$\implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(n-\sqrt{n}<X_1+\cdots+X_n<n+\sqrt{n})=\Phi(\sqrt{3})-\Phi(-\sqrt3)=2\Phi(\sqrt{3})-1$$

Comment: I'm not really understanding what was done from the first step to the second.

Comment: @RonaldB Mutiply above and below by $n$ and put values of $\mu $ and $\sigma$

Comment: Is the first equation the definition of the central limit theorem?

Comment: @RonaldB I thought so

Comment: mine was defined differently I guess? I'm sort of confused. Do we start from what was given and work towards definition? or do we start form the definition and work towards what we were given?

Comment: @RonaldB Back calculation always has the upper hand for me..You can go either way. Your choice

Comment: phew finally got it. thanks!

Comment: done and done. Do I need to standardize $\sqrt3$ or is that already been included? I'm getting 2$\Phi(\sqrt3)$=0.4582=0.9164 and subtracting 1 gives me something negative. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: @RonaldB You are making some mistake... $\sqrt{3}>0$ So $\Phi(\sqrt{3})>0.5$

Comment: I'm looking for 1.73 in the zscore table and what is given 0.4582.

Comment: @RonaldB  Do you know the a normal distribution curve looks like?

Comment: Yes, a bell curve

Comment: @RonaldB And if $X\sim N(0,1)$ what is the $P(X<1)$?

Comment: shouldnt it be $\Phi\left(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$

Comment: @RonaldB Yes . $\Phi\left({1-0\over 1}\right)$ . And whats its value?

Comment: it should be 0.341 ?

Comment: @RonaldB NO!! I think all this time you are looking at the **density** chart and not the **distribution** chart.. It will be $0.841$

Comment: phew ok got the right answer. Ok that should be it. Thanks again for all your help and patience!!!

Comment: @RonaldB Glad you did it.. A hearty welcome to you..